# Need help loading html into JQuery Mobile listview

Tags: jquery, listview, mobile, dynamic

I used to be quite good at JQuery but seem to have lost the plot now.

I have a simple container called user_list...

```
<div id="user_list" data-role="content">loading...<div>
```

In the  tag I have a script that loads a listview into the above mentioned div when the document is ready...

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#user_list').load('/getusers.php');
    });
</script>
```

A professional will be thinking now that the result will be a pile unformatted turd and they'd be right. So my question is, once I've loaded this to the div how do I make it look JQuery Mobiliy again?

I admit I haven't done a thorough search on Google, but in my defense I've been coding all day in Python and PHP so the move to Javascript has fried my brain.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Anthony

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter, I've got it!!!

So what I did was put a small script at the end of the dynamically loaded data to refresh the listview.

Here's the loaded data...

```
<ol data-role="listview" id="lv_users">
    <li>Joe Blogs</li>
    <li>Tom Thumb</li>
    <li>Big Cheese</li>
</ol>
```

So to make it look JQuery Mobilie again I just tagged this script onto the bottom...

```
<script language="javascript">
     $('#lv_users').listview();
</script>
```

Now when it loads up it bloody looks good again.